# Symfony2 Doctrine Annotations & UNIQ_ or FK_ customisation

Tags: symfony, annotations, doctrine

I'm using Symfony2 with Doctrine's Annotations to create references between tables. When creating the table, it looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `guardian` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fos_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_644860558C20A0FB` (`fos_user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_644860558C20A0FB` FOREIGN KEY (`fos_user_id`) REFERENCES `fos_user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The way this is done is by creating these Annotations in the code, and then running:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Here's the Annotations for one of the references:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="SF\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fos_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $fosUser;
```

As you can see from the "show create table;" above, the names of the key's, and constraints are rather non-human-friendly. I guess "UNIQ_644860558C20A0FB" is just "UNIQ_" and appending something random.

What I'd like to do is to actually give that a proper name, like "UNIQ_fos_user_id". The reason for this, is that if you get an error like below, it's really difficult to see quickly what's going on, and which key is the problem (especially if there's multiple unique's or foreign keys:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UNIQ_644860558C20A0FB'
```

I looked at the documentation [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html), but can't see any annotation attribute that will let me do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little investigation, you cannot define the constraint for primary or foreign keys. You can however change the unique constraint name :

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="ecommerce_products",uniqueConstraints={
 *     @UniqueConstraint(name="search_idx", columns={"name", "email"})})
 */
```

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-uniqueconstraint